# Flutter shared_preferences Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, package, sharedpreferences

I am facing a very strange problem when using [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and run the app I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.5.0/kotlin-compiler-26.5.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried the following:

1. Update flutter SDK / kotlin to the latest versions
2. command: Flutter doctor (to see if there is errors but everything goes fine)
3. Change the IDE ( Visual Code and Intellij)
4. - Create new flutter project without any modification in code.. and the project run without problems
   - I added [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package in pubspec.yaml and clicked package get, also without code modify.. and the project run without problems
   - Then I added [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) pubspec.yaml and clicked package get... then click run and the error appears.
   - I repeated last step by getting different versions of [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and every time I get the same error.
   - I tried all solutions provided on stackoverflow and all were useless.

Any help?

Comment: Can you try running 'flutter clean' from the terminal and try again?

Comment: @Arno unfortunately not worked... same error

Answer (score 5):

For my case, I just run:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

And after that, the error no longer occurs. Hope this helps