# Problem with building app-bundle or running release version of flutter project

Tags: flutter, apk, android-app-bundle

I have a problem while both building app-bundle and running my flutter project as a release.

[image]

I've already tried recompiling gradle, tried building from cmd and directly from android studio. Everything in flutter doctor is ok. Running app in debug mode works normally.

Tried Flutter Doctor - nothing abnormal

Tried everything from CMD and Directly from Android Studio - no difference

Error:

> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> [Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3.pom:12:3: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.
> [Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3.pom:12:3: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:generateReleaseRFile'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:releaseCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3.
>   Required by:
>   project :shared_preferences_android
>   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3.
>   > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3/flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-a4ff2c53d84ca78702bc3be6c7ef0788ffca01d3.pom
>   > An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.

> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 4s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            5,1s
> Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please do not include errors as screenshot (only). What the screen shot shows is pure text and can be copied to clipboard and inserted into your question. Please do so. text in images is often hard to read (bad contrast like in your screen shot) and is also not searchable e.g. by internet search engines.

Comment: Are you using non English words in your app?

Comment: Yes, but i don't use any non-english characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter shared\_preferences Build failed with an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739819/flutter-shared-preferences-build-failed-with-an-exception)

Comment: Nope, still got the same error